# How to portably check extremal values for SuSv3 data types?

Tags: c++, c, typedef, type-conversion, sus

By SuSv3, `ssize_t` is required to be a signed integer type. If I want to check if a value I calculate is larger than the maximal value allowed for such a data type, I could compare it to `INT_MAX`, which isn't nice.

Is there a more portable way this comparison can be done - a macro/function `f` that works as in

```
 f(<typedef'ed datatype>) = {maximum value allowed for <TDDT> on this system)?
```

, or a short sequence of such operations to the same sort?

System:
Ubuntu 12.04.
glibc 2.15
Kernel 3.2.0

P.S.: When googling this, I first thought that the gcc extension 'typeof' sounded promising; but it seemed to not help here (or does it?). This is to say I'm fine with anything that might be a gcc extension/attribute/etc.

Comment: "*I could compare it to INT_MAX, which isn't nice.*" Why? Or are your referring to comparing against `INT_MAX` for testing whether the value would fit into a `ssize_t`? Which indeed wouldn't be nice, as one should use `-((SIZE_MAX+1)/2-1)`.

Comment: @alk: Maybe my thinking is flawed, but I meant to stay compliant with whatever future changes to the SuS standard (or its successor) might require for an ssize_t (which is obviously just an example datatype). It seems very unlikely a change will happen, but what if in a future revision typdef int ssize_t (again, obviously just an example)? I'm working my way though Kerrisk, and the question came to my mind. Alternatively, would standard API coding use INT_MAX in such a case?

Comment: ...I meant to type typedef unsigned int ssize_t...

Comment: If you need a specific bit-width stick to the `u/intXY_t` integer types, for which you do not need to have MIN/MAX macros as their width is obvious and constant. For others like `s/size_t`, `u/intprt_t`, `ptrdiff_t` the bit-width isn't important, as they where explicitly introducded to cover bit-width issues away. So please excuse, but I do not really see the point of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unsigned arithmetic type, `(type)-1` is the maximum value. Since you don't know what the relative size of types is, cast to `uintmax_t`:

```
#define UNSIGNED_TYPE_MAX(t) ((uintmax_t)(t)-1)
if ((uintmax_t)x > UNSIGNED_TYPE_MAX(size_t)) puts("too large");
```

There is no such shortcut for signed types. In fact, I don't think there's any way of determining the largest value of a signed type in strictly portable C89 or C99, without using the corresponding constant, such as `SSIZE_MAX` for `ssize_t`. C99 specifies constants for each type designed for arithmetic defined in [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) for the types defined in ISO C. For types defined in POSIX but not in standard C, there are many values in [`limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html); note that they are the limit of what can be valid values for what the type is intended for, rather than the limit of what can fit in the type. For example, if `size_t` is a 32-bit type, then `SIZE_MAX` is guaranteed to be 2<sup>32</sup>-1, whereas `SSIZE_MAX` could be less than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 if the implementation doesn't support any byte count larger than that.

With the added assumption that integers are represented in binary and there are no padding bits, which is safe if you're limiting yourself to POSIX (where [`CHAR_BIT`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) is [always 8](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html#tag_13_48_05)), you can deduce the maximum value by computing the size of the type: there is one sign bit in a signed type, and everything else is a value bit.

```
#define SIGNED_TYPE_MAX(t) (((uintmax_t)1 << (sizeof(t) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1)
```

Note that things like “double until it stops growing” or “shove in the bit pattern 0111…111” are dodgy. The C standard says that the behavior is undefined for signed types, and GCC takes advantage of this to perform optimizations on operations on signed types that can result in the wrong value if an overflow happens. For example, it might perform computations in a larger-size register, so that the overflow turns out not to happen.

Comment: Tyvm! This is clever, but please allow me some follow-up questions (as said, I'm fairly new to this): (i) what exactly is uintmax_t (the name makes it rather clear, but it's the first time I see the data type), (ii) I wasn't even aware that the constant SSIZE_MAX existed (but now found it in posix1_lim.h (thanks!) - but, say, none for SIZE_MAX exists, correct?, so is there a system for which POSIX typdefs such constants exist?, and (iii) what exactly is CHAR_BIT (I understand the logic of your last #define; but didn't know this one either).

Comment: If you think this merits asking a separate question to not unduly free-ride on your one answer I can upvote, I'm happy to ask another question. --added--On a second look, I noticed that SSIZE_MAX is actually LONG_MAX, so my original suggestion to use INT_MAX is doubly suspicious.

Comment: @gnometorule: Search for the standard C headers `<limits.h>`, `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: @gnometorule I've added links to the Single Unix spec for the appropriate headers. Use the standard header neames, `posix1_lim.h` is an internal, non-portable header name. `SIZE_MAX` does exist. `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits per byte. Not all POSIX types have defined limits, only the ones for computations, not all the ones for system handles such as `uid_t`.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much. Following @mafso 's suggestion, I already tracked down uintmax_t in stdint.h, and will now check for the rest.

Comment: Actually, Gilles, to match the logic of what you describe, the 2nd define should - I believe - actually be as follows: #define SIGNED_TYPE_MAX(t) (((uintmax_t) 1 << ((sizeof(t) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)) - 1) (-1 to account for sign bit; then -1 to account for 2^N-1 - I'm sure it's just a typo).

Comment: @gnometorule Fixed, thanks. That wouldn't even have worked for an unsigned type that happened to be as large as uintmax_t, since a shift by the type size has undefined behavior (though it's often truncated to a shift to 0, which would have worked equally well here).

Comment: Additive operators have a higher precedence than shift operators, so what you wrote is equivalent to `(((uintmax_t)1 << (sizeof(t) * CHAR_BIT - 2)))`

Comment: @mafso: You mist be reading the brackets wrong (there are many); it's ( (... << ...) -1). Also, not having a bracket around sizeof(t)*CHAR_BIT gives you a gcc warning, for what that's worth (as they are not syntactically needed, I didn't have them at first as well). In any case, macro per comment/fixed in answer gives the right value; yours - as you I am sure are aware  - not.